# How to Toast in ApplicationSyncAdapter Android?

Tags: android

I have tried by making toast in activity, Fragments and Services by using runOnUIthread concept.

How to make toast in ApplicationSyncAdapter in Android?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Why do you think that showing a `Toast` in a `SyncAdapter` is what the user will want?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String text = (String)s.getSelectedItem();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
        }
// this by Java
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWI07.png

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code on the main thread like this:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(/*Your runnable*/)
```